# Unwrapping everything in the same direction

Tags: matlab, graph, angle, atan2

I asked a similar question yesterday about how to avoid 'jumps' in data when using `atan2d`. The function operates on a scale of -180 to 180, like this:

[image: Unit circle with atan2d]

When a number crosses over 180, it goes directly to -180, making line plots [very ugly and not intuitive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XJNW.png) to read. It was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784027/3845377) that I use `unwrap` to fix this, which I thought it did. However, today I encountered a graph that looks like this:

[image: Graph with weird translation].

The jump is fixed, but in its place a line is translated to the top. If you plot these three lines, they are very close, like they should be (-180 and 180 are the same place still, like with the `atan2d` graph). I want my graph to reflect the way the angles really are - very close together.

Per request by David K, here is the code I am using to calculate the the angle for one of the lines. `rec,ret` is an ordered set of coordinates, and `recx` and `recy` are the x and y values of them, respectively. I then plot the result of theta_r onto a regular figure.

```
for i=1:length(recx)
    dy(i,1)=((recy(i)-rety(i)));
    dx(i,1)=((recx(i)-retx(i)));
    sloperight(i,1)=(dy(i)/dx(i));
    theta_r(i,1)=atan2d(dy(i),dx(i));

end
theta_r = 180/pi * unwrap(theta_r * pi/180);
```

**My Question**

How can I make the unwrap function only unwrap in one direction (make all angles with respect to clockwise on a circle, or counterclockwise) instead of unwrapping in the closest direction? Or should I use something other than `unwrap` to make the graph look good?

Comment: It might be easier to figure out the problem if you post the MATLAB code that made the graph (including the part that uses `unwrap`). From the documentaiton, it seems `unwrap` will eliminate jumps in a one-dimensional array but will not eliminate jumps between columns of a two-dimensional array, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a thought: pick one of the values in your set of data, for example, the first value in the first "line" of data. Set `angle0` to that value, and for each array of data, `A`, make an "adjusted" copy of `A` as follows: `wrapTo180(A - angle0) + angle0`, and plot the new data.

Just be sure to use the same value of `angle0` for all the data you plot on one graph.

This approach can have its own problems with some sets of data (for example if the angles progressively increase through a wide enough range, this approach will produce "jumps" that aren't present in the original data), but since you know the data are all clustered around one angular value (modulo 360 degrees), it should be OK for your graph.

Answer (score 1):

I left this question open when I left my computer, and thereby [nerdsniped](http://xkcd.com/356/) myself this morning.

Below is some code to put David K's answer into practice. Use the provided random seed to guarantee a decent example. Comment that line out to see different examples every time.

```
%Seed maintenance
%    This seed seems to demonstrate the desired behavior. Comment this out
%    to see multiple examples
rng(523205203)

%Parameters
N = 500;
commonRate = 10;
independentRate = 2;
nSeries = 4;

%Some random data
common = randn(N*2,1)*commonRate;
independent = randn(N*2,nSeries)*independentRate;

%Build up some interesting data series
data = cumsum(bsxfun(@plus,common, independent), 1);
data = data((N+1):end, :);

%Setup observed data, observing modulated data
observedData = mod(data, 360)-180;

%Utility functions
%    Basic unwrapping, in deg
unwrap_deg            = @(x) unwrap(x/180*pi)*180/pi;           
%    Unwrapping, using an arbitrary offset, in deg
unwrapToValue_deg     = @(x, value) unwrap_deg(x-value)+value;  
%    Basic unwrapping, in dim 1, after adjusting columns based on row 1
equalizeAndUnwrap_deg = @(x) unwrap_deg(...
    bsxfun(@plus, ...
    unwrapToValue_deg(x(1,:),x(1,1)) - x(1,:), ...   %Per column, add the difference ebtween row 1 and the unwrapped row 1
    observedData)...    
    );

%Use functions to correct observred data
unwrappedObservedData = unwrap_deg(observedData);
equalizedUnwrappedObservedData = equalizeAndUnwrap_deg(observedData);

%Plot
figure(2932323)
subplot(311)
plot(observedData,'.')
subplot(312)
plot(unwrappedObservedData,'.')
subplot(313)
plot(equalizedUnwrappedObservedData,'.')
```